# Is it ok to use "yet" with the present tense?

Tags: grammar

Assuming that the question `Do you have the report?` is ok, is it ok to ask: `Do you have the report yet?` Or generally, is it ok to use the present tense with `yet`?

**As for the search effort:**

I have found an exemplary application of the word "yet" in the present tense only in conjunction with the verb "to be". As in a question:

> *Are* we there yet?

or as in the provided answer:

> There *is* plenty of time yet.

I have not found examples of "yet" in the present tense with verbs other than "to be". These examples have raised my doubts about the usage of yet. I have not found any strict rule which forbids it but it does not mean it is allowed, or at least acceptable.

Comment: I would probably rephrase it as, 'Do you have the report yet?'. Yet is a conjunction— it can be used in all tenses I should imagine.

Comment: @Deonyi: *Close, yet no cigar!* It's a conjunction in *my* usage there (where the sense is ***but***), but in OP's context above I think it's more likely called an adverb.

Comment: The first place to look is a dictionary, find one dictionary that also include sample sentences. [Longman Dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/yet), [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/yet), and [Your Dictionary](https://www.yourdictionary.com/yet) if the examples show usage with a different auxiliary verbs, and with different tenses, it's more than likely that the equivalent interrogative forms can be used.

Comment: I'm voting against re-opening, as your edit fails to address the reason it was closed. All good online dictionaries give examples of present-tense usage with verbs other than "be" - in fact, "be" is much less common than examples with "have". Apart from the dictionaries @Mari-LouA links to, see also [these](https://www.onelook.com/?w=yet&ls=a), e.g. Merriam-Webster, Cambridge, Collins, Macmillan – or *look at the opening clause in the answer below, and read the link*. Alternatively, "**consider if your question suits our [ell.se] site better**".

Answer (score 2):

I have yet to see this question answered, so I'll post an answer myself. Better yet, I'm posting it now!

**Short answer: Yes**, nothing wrong with using it with the present tense.

The Cambridge Dictionary has in its grammar

> There’s plenty of time yet.

among many other examples. [I archived the webpage for future reference.](https://web.archive.org/web/20190603133527/https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/linking-words-and-expressions/yet)

If it is not yet clear, I am sure somebody else will come up with a better answer.